# In Zend Framework 2 RBAC or ACL. Which is recomended?

Tags: zend-framework, acl, rbac

I am about to implement access control in my ZF2 project. I am checking both RBAC and ACL.
Which one would be best suited over the other? and why?

And which one would be supported well by Zend in the future?

I googled it, but couldn't get answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use ZF2 ACL probably you have to do a few other things like put in place firewalls, load ACL configuration and setup rules etc.

I was quite happy with ZF1 ACL but a bit pain was to setup and keep up-to-date resources (in our case model/controller/action).

In ZF2 you should use routes - routeMatch or Controller match. I found quite useful ZfcRbac which is quite similar to RBAC but it does extra few bits.

It might be easier to start there.

[ZfcRbac](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcRbac)